# ¿Por qué un enumerado no puede ser una plantilla?

Tags: c++, c++11, enum, template

> ```
> enumeration cannot be a template
> ```

Ese es el error mostrado cuando intento compilar con [BCC64](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/BCC64.EXE,_the_C++_64-bit_Windows_Compiler) (basado en Clang) el siguiente código:

```
template <typename T> enum class enumerado : T
{
    a,b,c,d,e
};
```

Primero, pensé que esta prohibición explícita se debía a las limitaciones del tipo subyacente de los enumerados ya que si el tipo del enumerado puede ser un tipo plantilla, podría resultar en enumerados incorrectos, sin embargo cuando intentamos esto:

```
template <typename A> struct estructura
{
    enum class enumerado : A
    {
        a,b,c,d,e
    };
};
```

Compila sin problemas siempre que el tipo `A` cumpla con las limitaciones requeridas por el tipo subyacente de enumerados; de no ser así (tanto en un enumerado anidado en un objeto como en un enumerado contexto global) podemos ver otro error específico, como era de esperar:

```
enum class enumerado : mi_clase_fabulosa
{
    a,b,c,d,e
};
```

> ```
> non-integral type 'mi_clase_fabulosa' is an invalid underlying type
> ```

Así pues, este es el motivo por el que me pregunto ¿por qué está explícitamente prohibido crear un enumerado plantilla cuando ya hay control sobre su tipo subyacente? ¿Dónde en el estándar de C++ está definida esta limitación?

---

Esta es una traducción de [la misma pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914457/why-enumeration-cannot-be-a-template) en la versión Inglesa.

Comment: Cómo curiosidad cmentar que seguramente con la flag `-pedantic-errors` esto compila. Lo cuál dice mucho del error.!!! haha

Comment: @MiquelColl ¿*seguramente compila*? ¿Lo has probado? ¡¿Con qué compilador?! :O

Comment: http://rextester.com/UIZ27560 aquí hay un código muy parecido que sí compila. He pùesto tu código y.... no haha. Lo siento!

Comment: @MiquelColl dos cosas: 1. si no instancias el template es como si no existiese y 2. En tu caso el tipo del enum no es dependiente del tipo del template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta original en [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914457/) ya tiene respuesta aceptada, que puedo trascribir acá: 
Por definición [Estándar C++ 14.1], o por quedar fuera de la definición,

> A template defines a family of classes or functions or an alias for a family of types.

Esto es: ''Un template define una familia de clases o de funciones o un alias para una familia de tipos.''

Y como un enum no es ninguno de esos, no puede ser un template.

Entonces, agrego yo, la limitación en el estándar es implícita, no explícita.

Comment: Si, acepté esa respuesta en el original, iba a responderme a mi mismo pero me has ahorrado el trabajo :)